# Is it safe to use a user input as a colum name in sequelize where?

Tags: sequelize.js

Is it safe to use a user input as a colum name in sequelize where?

Like this:

```
var userInput ={"I am unsafe": "I am also an sql injection"};

Post.findAll({
  where: userInput
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Is it safe to use a user input as a colum name in sequelize where?**

Depends upon what do you mean by safe ,

If you are just asking for where condition , in your case sequlize will throw an error , if user enters invalid column name ,

User can't modify any kind of stuff by just where condition.

In this case you are good to go. Just handle all the errors properly.

Comment: Why does sequelize throws an error? Because the database throws an error or because sequelize validates the column name itself? I just want to be sure, that where conditions can't send a sql injection to the database

Comment: Because of database , I long as I know injection won't be the case here